# How to pass command with parameters to xargs

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

`echo ls -l -a / | xargs sh -c`

How to make above command work?

it only list current directory

seems only ls is passed to xargs

`echo '"ls -l -a /"' | xargs sh -c` would work though, but the input I got has no ""

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-c` flag to `sh` only accepts one argument while xargs is splitting the arguments on whitespace - that's why the double quoting works (one level to make it a single word for the shell, one for xargs).

If you use the `-0` or `null` argument to `xargs` your particular case will work:

```
echo ls -l -a / | xargs -0 sh -c
```

Comment: Other option: `echo ls -l -a / | xargs -I '{}' sh -c "{}"`

Answer (score 18):

Source: http://www.unixmantra.com/2013/12/xargs-all-in-one-tutorial-guide.html

as mentioned by @darklion, **-I** denoted the argument list marker and **-c** denotes bash command to run on every input  line to xargs.

Simply print the input to xargs:

```
ls -d */ | xargs echo
#One at a time
ls -d */ | xargs -n1 echo
```

More operations on every input:

```
ls -d */  | xargs -n1 -I {} /bin/bash -c ' echo {}; ls -l {}; '
```

You can replace **{}** with customized string as:

```
ls -d */  | xargs -n1 -I file /bin/bash -c ' echo file; ls -l file; '
```